nondeterministic reductions?
Has anyone thought about nondeterministic reductions before? In the sense that the reduction mapping is in $\text{FNP}$.
So we say $A \le_{FNP} B$ if there is a function $f \in \text{FNP}$ such that $x \in A \iff f(x) \in B$.
Informally, one can recognize a proper reduction output in poly-time if it is given, but one cannot necessarily compute the proper reduction output.
We are hoping to use this sort of reduction to prove ''hardness'' for $\text{QMA}$.
Does something like this exist and make sense?

In your question, is $f$ a proper function in which every input $x$ goes to exactly one output $f(x)$? I think the definitions I can find offhand for $\mathbf{FNP}$ allow more generally for relations which might map an input to many different outputs, or an input to no outputs.

How bout something like $x \in A \Leftrightarrow \exists w : f(x,w) \in B$.

Yes, people have studied this. So-called $\gamma$-reductions were introduced by Adleman & Manders. History, further refs, and further developments in this paper by Chung & Ravikumar, which also talks about the "strong nondeterministic reductions" introduced by Long.
$\gamma$-reductions are essentially $\mathsf{NPMV}_t$ "many-one" reductions, in the sense that there is a nondet polytime machine $M$ such that, for every input $x$, at least one computation path of $M(x)$ accepts, and  every accepting computation path outputs some $y$ such that $x \in A \Leftrightarrow y \in B$.
Long's strong nondet reductions are the Turing-reduction version of this: there is a nondet oracle TM with a $B$ oracle such that at least one path of the machine halts, and every halting path gives the correct answer as to whether $x$ is in $A$.
It would also make sense to talk about an $\mathsf{NPSV}_t = \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP} \cap \mathsf{coNP}}$ version of $\gamma$-reductions - where all accepting computation paths of the reducing machine $M$ output the same $y$. I seem to recall this has been studied as well, but can't find a reference at the moment.
See also:

https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-16761-7_70
Nondeterministic logspace reductions

